# Setting up private Ethereum blockchain using static nodes

Tags: go-ethereum

I have to connect to 4 nodes. In static - nodes.json file I put all the 4 enodes with their IP addresses, each with a different `rpc port` and `--port number` but the same network ID and genesis file.

When I am running `net.peerCount` it displays 0. I am not understanding what is the problem.